# Almost half curl tests are being timeout

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, ssl, libcurl

I was performing some SSL test using `curl(curl 7.19.7)` to one of my apache server/ubuntu. But I found something strange on my test machine which was running on linux and test program is in C. Posting whole program will be clumsy so please see what parameters were in test program:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, url_req); //https://10.240.253.5
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT , tout_curl);//10 seconds
```

With above options my program ran around 1.2M test to single host and I got timeout for 600k tests . In micro level these are 250 tests on the interval of 180 seconds . When I run some 10 queries per minute I never gets timeout . But in heavy load it is giving timeout.

I tried to capture packets but was not able to understand those. I have recently started work in curl and SSL/TLS . So any quick solution/suggetion for my problem is highly appreciated .

PS:I am seeing some posts that this scenario is very CPU intensive . So I think increasing resources . may be timeout error get resolved.

PS2: These tests were multiple threaded say one thread per test so 250 threads per 180 seconds.

Comment: I have two doubt/workarounds please verify . If I use any strong computer for tests OR Is there any way to ignore this heavy handshake and cert process (here i am totally blind)

Comment: Almost dead topic for 25days anyways I found that it was issue with sharing curl handle simultaneously in multiple threads [see curl doc](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html#Multi-threading)

Comment: I am curious if you were able to come up with an approach, given you discovered the handle contention between threads?  That is, did you implement some kind of thread safe construct? (mutex, unique handles, ...)